# Login-AzureRmAccount not working in Microsoft Azure Government

Tags: azure, azure-gov

I am able to login to my Microsoft Azure Government subscription account via the [Azure Government portal](https://portal.azure.us), when I log in through Powershell:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -Environment AzureUSGovernment
```

I get the following error:

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application

Answer (score 3):

**Upgrading to the latest version of the AzureRM powershell module will resolve this issue.** The same thing applies for Azure CLI, Storage Explorer and any other Azure tools.

The issue is that the older version of these tools use an older Azure AD endpoint:

```
https://login-us.microsoftonline.com
```

The new/current endpoint that the updated modules/tools use is:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.us
```

See [the Azure Government AAD Authority Update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuregov/2018/04/03/azure-government-aad-authority-endpoint-update/) blog post for more details on this.